# Trying to build a function in google sheets for sending emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to create a google sheet formula for send emails through MailApp.

```
/**
*
*
*@customfunction
*/
function SendIssueMails(x) 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("IssueCourses");
  var email = sheet.getRange(x).getValue();
  var subject = "Issue updated that needs resolution";
  var body = "Please go to your issue tracker. You have been assigned an Issue that need resolution";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
  return "sent";
}
```

This is the code i wrote such that when i put this formula in sheets with x as email ID, its saying i dont have permission. i gave permission in appscript by sending a manual email but it still show that permission required and i dont know where to give that permission.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

> If your custom function throws the error message You do not have permission to call X service., the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.

You can't use a service like MailApp in a custom function. You'll need to trigger sending the email in a different way. Perhaps an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) configured to run when a certain cell is edited?

Answer (score 0):

Diego is right, custom functions on spreadsheet can not request access to personal data, so you can only use the services from this list:

> Supported services

Cache
HTML
JDBC
Language
Lock
Maps
Properties
Spreadsheet:
Cannot open other spreadsheets (SpreadsheetApp.openById() or SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()).
URL Fetch
Utilities
XML

On which you'll not find GmailApp

> If your custom function throws the error message You do not have permission to call X service., the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.

As the documentation says:

> To use a service other than those listed above, create a custom menu
>   that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom
>   function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user
>   for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps
>   Script services.

If you are looking on how to call your function from Sheets, you should look at Custom menus:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus